# Looking for the top 10 scores between students listed in two tables (sqlite3)

Tags: sql, sqlite, union-all

Here's the code that I'm trying with but the results were not correct or only showing the column with names:

```
sql = ("Select * from (Select name, SCORES from  Table 1 where SCORES>0 order by SCORES) "
       "UNION ALL "
       "Select * from (Select name, SCORES from  Table 2 where SCORES >0 order by SCORES) "
       "ORDER BY SCORES DESC Limit 10")
```

Here's a sample of table 1

| name | Gender | SCORES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Steve | Male | 1200 |
| Robert | Male | 1600 |

Here's a sample of table 2

| name | Gender | SCORES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cindy | Female | 3500 |
| Judy | Female | 4500 |

Comment: Don't you get name and SCORES columns in your result? What do you want?

Answer (score 1):

Simply `UNION ALL` the tables, order by scores descending, and pick the 10 first rows:

```
select name, scores from table1
union all
select name, scores from table2
order by scores desc
limit 10
```